# can not use WpfToolkit on VS 2015

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, xamlparseexception

I have a WPF project working on .NET 4.0, i started using  Visual Studio 2015

but i have got problem that wpf toolkit not working with so i have got

`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`

example :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:TimePicker />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check from the next link last "feature" of `Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit Plus
New version 2.8`

http://xceed.com/pages/topmenu/downloads/updates.aspx?periodcode=lb

> For themes different than Windows 8, the exception of type
>   "Initialization of 'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.XXX' will no longer be thrown in
>   Visual Studio 2015. This affects all controls of the toolkit.

You need to update a toolkit to latest version